# Передача массива структур из вторичного потока в главный с использованием сигналов и слотов

Tags: c++, qt4

Не могу передать из вторичного потока в главный массив структур. Гугл не помог. Версия Qt4.7.8

```
#ifndef SENSORMANAGER_H
#define SENSORMANAGER_H
#include <QObject>
struct massifVoltageAndIndex{  // наша структура которую хочу передать
unsigned short int Voltage;
unsigned short int index;
 };
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(massifVoltageAndIndex)
class SensorManager : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
massifVoltageAndIndex Balanser[247];
public:
explicit SensorManager(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
void signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex& Balanser); // наш сигнал для передачи структуры
public slots:
};
#endif // SENSORMANAGER_H
```

Передаю сигнал:

```
emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser);
```

Получаю ошибку на emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser);

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘SensorManager::signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex (*)[247])’
emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser);
                            ^
```

В чем дело ?

Организация коннекта со вторым потоком.

```
   sensormanager = new(SensorManager);
   QObject::connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(signalInfoAuto(const 
   massifVoltageAndIndex &)),this, SLOT(slot(const massifVoltageAndIndex 
   &s)));
   QThread* pThread=new(QThread);
   sensormanager->moveToThread(pThread);
   QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), sensormanager, 
   SLOT(slotAutoModeBalancer()));
   pThread->start();
```

Comment: Я Вам писал в чате по предыдущему вопросу :)) Попробуйте **emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser)** или **emit signalInfoAuto(&Balanser[0])** Есть у меня предположение, что в варианте **emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser)** получается неверный тип параметра. Т.к. Balanser у Вас массив ,то получается не передача указателя на структуру, а передача указателя на указатель на структуру.

Comment: Пробовал не помогло.
НА emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser[0]);
ошибка error: no matching function for call to ‘SensorManager::signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex*)’
  emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser[0]);
                                   ^
emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser);
ошибка 
error: no matching function for call to ‘SensorManager::signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex [247])’
  emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser);
                              ^

Comment: вы вызываете сигнал с параметром `Balanser**`, тогда как сам сигнал ожидает параметр `Balanser&`, напишите `signalInfoAuto(Balanser[0])`. к тому же при соединении сигнала и слота у вас откуда-то появляется константность параметра, которой нет ни в сигнале, ни в слоте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слот принимает постоянную **ссылку** на структуру `massifVoltageAndIndex`:

```
QObject::connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(signalInfoAuto(const 
massifVoltageAndIndex &)),this, SLOT(slot(const massifVoltageAndIndex 
&s)));
```

Вы же передаёте **указатель** на массив структур: `emit signalInfoAuto(& Balanser);`

Либо передайте ссылку на одну структуру:

```
emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser[0]); //или другой индекс, который уместен
```

Либо слот должен принимать указатель на структуру, тогда должно сработать:

```
emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser);
```

Comment: в коде автора сигнал объявлен как `void signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex& Balanser)`, а в конекте уже как константный, хз что тут верно)

Comment: Нет я хочу принять весь массив структур. 
Вот так сделал
signals:
void signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex* Balanser);
Передаю сигнал
emit signalInfoAuto(Balanser);
Коннект
QObject::connect(sensormanager, SIGNAL(signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex* Balanser)),this, SLOT(slot(massifVoltageAndIndex*)));
Слот
void slot(massifVoltageAndIndex*);
void MainWindow::slot(massifVoltageAndIndex*)
{
Как принять данные массива структур?
}

Comment: @zhilenkov, "Как принять данные массива структур?". Вы передаёте указатель на массив. Теперь вы можете получить доступ к членам массива с помощью оператора `[]`

Comment: Сделал вот так:
  int i = 0;
  i = massifVoltageAndIndex[0].Index;
Получил ошибку:
error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
   i = massifVoltageAndIndex[0].Index;

Comment: А все понял сделал вот так 
void MainWindow::slot(massifVoltageAndIndex* balancer_1)
{
balancer_1[0].Index;
}

Comment: Когда запускаю программу получаю сообщение:
Object::connect: No such signal SensorManager::signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex* Balanser) 
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')